# ionic cordova run android not working

Tags: java, cordova, environment-variables, ionic3

when I run `ionic cordova run android` command It shows an error like this.
[image]

I installed java latest version (jdk 9.0.4)

I set **JAVA_HOME** in system variables like this...

[image]

[image]

How do i solve this issue and run my project perfectly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use jdk 8...and try. I dont think 9 works yet

Comment: S0, you suggest me uninstall JDK 9 and install JDK 8. Ok, i'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First locate your `java_home` and set it to variable `path`(at the end - separeted with `;`)

[image]

It works with version 9 too. Good luck!